# ConcurrentModificationException in PostUpdateListener

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, listener

Recently I've implemented a **PostUpdate** Hibernate Listener to make some *Special Audit* about the operation done:

assuming the root entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="plan")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@DynamicUpdate
@DynamicInsert
public class Plan implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String protocol;


    @Lob
    private String description;

    private String title;

    @Type(type="service.dao.hibernate.enumeration.PlanStateUserType")
    @Column(name="plan_state_id")
    @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    private PlanState planState;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="plan",fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true)
    @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    private Collection<PlanAudit> planAudits;   

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="send_date")
    private Date sendDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="approval_date")
    private Date approvalDate;

    @Column(name="extension_days")
    private int extensionDays;

    @Column(name="extension_reporting_days")
    private int extensionReportingDays;


    public Plan() {
        planPurposes = new ArrayList<PlanPurpose>();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProtocol() {
        return this.protocol;
    }

    public void setProtocol(String protocol) {
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }

    public Collection<PlanAudit> getPlanAudits() {
        return planAudits;
    }

    public void setPlanAudits(Collection<PlanAudit> planAudits) {
        this.planAudits = planAudits;
    }   

    public void addAudit(User user, PlanState previous, PlanState next, Date operationDate){
        PlanAudit audit = new PlanAudit();

        audit.setPlan(this);
        audit.setOperationDate(operationDate);
        audit.setUser(user);
        audit.setPlanStateFrom(previous);
        audit.setPlanStateTo(next);
        this.planAudits.add(audit);     
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public PlanState getPlanState() {
        return planState;
    }

    public void setPlanState(PlanState planState) {
        this.planState = planState;
    }

    public Date getSendDate() {
        return sendDate;
    }

    public void setSendDate(Date sendDate) {
        this.sendDate = sendDate;
    }

    public Date getApprovalDate() {
        return approvalDate;
    }

    public void setApprovalDate(Date approvalDate) {
        this.approvalDate = approvalDate;
    }

    public int getExtensionDays() {
        return extensionDays;
    }

    public void setExtensionDays(int extensionDays) {
        this.extensionDays = extensionDays;
    }

    public int getExtensionReportingDays() {
        return extensionReportingDays;
    }

    public void setExtensionReportingDays(int extensionReportingDays) {
        this.extensionReportingDays = extensionReportingDays;
    }
}
```

then the *audit entity*:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="plan_audit")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
public class PlanAudit implements Serializable { //extends SimpleAuditedEntity 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="operation_date")
    private Date operationDate;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Plan
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="plan_id")
    private Plan plan;

    @Type(type="service.dao.hibernate.enumeration.PlanStateUserType")
    @Column(name="plan_state_from_id")
    @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    private PlanState planStateFrom;

    @Type(type="service.dao.hibernate.enumeration.PlanStateUserType")
    @Column(name="plan_state_to_id")
    @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    private PlanState planStateTo;


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    private User user;

    public PlanAudit() {
    }


    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getOperationDate() {
        return this.operationDate;
    }

    public void setOperationDate(Date operationDate) {
        this.operationDate = operationDate;
    }

    public Plan getPlan() {
        return this.plan;
    }

    public void setPlan(Plan plan) {
        this.plan = plan;
    }

    public PlanState getPlanStateFrom(){
        return this.planStateFrom;
    }

    public void setPlanStateFrom(PlanState planState){
        this.planStateFrom = planState;
    }

    public PlanState getPlanStateTo(){
        return this.planStateTypeTo;
    }

    public void setPlanStateTo(PlanState planState){
        this.planStateTo = planState;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

Then the listener is :

```
@Component
public class PlanListener implements PostUpdateEventListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Autowired
    private UserContext userContext;


    private int getPropertyIndex(String[] array, String name) {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i] == name)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    private void setValue(Object[] currentState, String[] propertyNames, String propertyToSet, Object value, Object entity) {
         int index = ArrayUtils.indexOf(propertyNames, propertyToSet);
         if (index >= 0) {
              currentState[index] = value;
              } else {
                   //Log.error("Field '" + propertyToSet + "' not found on entity '" + entity.getClass().getName() + "'.");
              }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {
        Object entity = event.getEntity();
        if(entity instanceof Plan)
        {
            int stateProperty = getPropertyIndex(
                    event.getPersister().getPropertyNames(), 
                    "planStateType");

            if(stateProperty != -1) {
                PlanState prev = (PlanState)event.getOldState()[stateProperty];
                PlanState next = ((Plan)entity).getPlanState();

                if(prev.getEnumeratedValue() != 
                   next.getEnumeratedValue()) {
                    Plan target = (Plan) event.getEntity();
                    target.addAudit(
                            userContext.getCurrentUser(), 
                            prev), 
                            next), 
                            new Date());
                }
            }
        }       
    }



    @Override
    public boolean requiresPostCommitHanding(EntityPersister persister) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, in the Listener if I get the User object from the *UserContext object* and then proceed I get a **ConcurrentModificationException**, if I set a user id instead the User object everything goes. I saw after time & time debugging that just reading the User object from the Session makes the exception happen.

This is the exception stack trace:

```
- 2016-04-05 17:18:17 ERROR org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [null]
 java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.next(Collections.java:1042)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:558)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2352)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:581)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at service.impl.PlanServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$299741bf.updatePlan(<generated>)
    at controller.presentation.FinancialController.postConfirm(FinancialController.java:643)
    at controller.presentation.FinancialController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$4face017.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651)
    at controller.presentation.FinancialController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ff2cd793.postConfirm(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:86)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:248)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:167)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:761)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any idea? I'm going to be crazy, nothing anywhere, google, SO, forums.. Nothing!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Enver instead of rolling my own audit logging mechanism. You should also add a StackTrace to see where the `ConcurrentModificationException` originates from because otherwise it is very difficult to spot such an issue.

It may be that it is caused by some bug too, in which case we need a replicating test case for this.

Also, the `PostUpdateEventListener` is triggered in the `doAfterTransactionCompletion` phase. Enver applies all changes with a temporary Session, so you'd have to do something like that too.

Comment: Thanks for the details, but if I won't use Envers, It's better to use a PreUpdate or what else event?

Comment: There are some issues with your custom audit strategy. You are using entities which might be deleted in a future release causing FK constraints on audit entries. The audit entries shouldn't have any FK, or use associations. I'd just dump the row state using a DB trigger instead.

Comment: I added the exception stacktrace

Comment: The `PostUpdateEventListener` shoudl be called in `doAfterTransactionCompletion`, while you get the execption in `beforeTransactionCompletion`. Is it an older vesrion of Hibernate?

Comment: no I'm using hibernate 5, and the same exception I have in the PreUpdateEventListener.

Comment: Is the Session reused after commit?

Comment: No, the session isn't used after commit, session is managed by Spring OpenSessionInViewFilter. What I saw is if I don't read the User object (in this case) everything works, but if I read the User object then I get the exception above

Comment: It's hard to tell. You'll have to debug, and if you spot a Hibernate issue, you can submit a replicating test case to a Jira issue.

Comment: Ok, don't worry, and any way many thanks for your attention! I solved changing the audit entity so I haven't to read the User object which cause the exception. If I get time to post to Jira with a test case I will, take in mind replicating a test case for that is not so simple...